# Traefik Ingress Kubernetes - Conditional CORS Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have two frontend applications that access the same API gateway:
`example.com` and
`admin.example.com`

I'm using Traefik as my ingress controller. I currently have the following annotation in my k8s ingress configuration:

`ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://example.com || Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE`

I also would like to handle `https://admin.example.com` within the same block. Is there a way that I can setup a conditional expression here dependant on the origin URL that the traffic is originating from? `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not acceptable for my usecase (browsers complain).

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? We are experiencing a similar issue now, couldn't find good answers yet

Comment: I offloaded that logic into the application layer itself as I had to move onto other priorities, which I didn't want to have to do. However, if you do find a solution please post it here... I'll do the same. :)

Comment: Have you all checked issue closed recently by Traefik [Github Issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/3809)